# How to fetch JavaScript from server, track download progress, and not use `unsafe-eval` in Content-Security-Policy?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, fetch, content-security-policy, webassembly

I have a heavy JavaScript file on the server (> 3MB). I want to load the page fast and show a loading progress bar to the user. Currently, I am using [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) and [WritableStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WritableStream) to download the data and to track the download progress as:

```js
let resource = await fetch('heavy_file.js')
resource.clone().body.pipeTo(new WritableStream({
    write(t) { on_receive(t.length) }
}))
```

And then I am using the [Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) to evaluate it. This has several problems. How can I:

- Load the script preferably using `fetch` (I'm using the same method to load WASM files, I want to track their download progress as well, and the [WebAssembly.compileStreaming](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WebAssembly/compileStreaming) API requires the usage of `fetch`).
- Track the download progress in a way that would work across modern browsers nowadays.
- Be able to use this solution without enabling `script-src 'unsafe-eval'` in [Content-Security-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy)?

PS.
Of course, currently, we need to use `script-src 'wasm-eval'` in Chrome when loading WASM files until [the bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=948834&can=1&q=wasm-eval) is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1

If you can calculate the hash of the script you're loading in advance (if it's not something generated dynamically), then a simple option to avoid

> enabling script-src 'unsafe-eval' in Content-Security-Policy

would be to add only a hash of that specific script into the CSP header - this will still ensure that you're not executing any untrusted code, while allowing you to load and execute script manually.

MDN has some more examples of implementing such CSP policies [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src#Unsafe_inline_script).

As for loading itself, you have two different paths from here:

#### Option 1.1

Combine the hash with a CSP3 policy `unsafe-hashes` which will allow you to keep using `Function` or `eval` like you currently, while still limiting code only to trusted.

For example, if you have a script like

```js
alert('Hello, world.');
```

then your CSP header should contain

```
Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'unsafe-hashes' 'sha256-qznLcsROx4GACP2dm0UCKCzCG-HiZ1guq6ZZDob_Tng='
```

Unfortunately, CSP level 3, or, at least, this option is [supported only in Chromium](https://caniuse.com/#search=unsafe-hashes) at the moment of writing.

#### Option 1.2

Instead of using `Function` or `eval`, you can dynamically create a script tag from JavaScript, populate its `textContent` with your response content and inject it into the DOM:

```js
let resource = await fetch('heavy_file.js')
resource.clone().body.pipeTo(new WritableStream({
    write(t) { on_receive(t.length) }
}));
resource.text().then(res => {
  let s = document.createElement('script');
  s.textContent = res;
  document.head.appendChild(s);
});
```

In this case you only need to add the hash of the script to the CSP and it will work across all browsers:

```
Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'sha256-qznLcsROx4GACP2dm0UCKCzCG-HiZ1guq6ZZDob_Tng='
```

### Option 2

If you do want to support dynamically generated scripts, then your only option might be to move your progress-tracking code to a Service Worker, and then use [`Client.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Client/postMessage) to communicate progress to a script on the page.

This will work for any content served from your origin, but only once Service Worker is installed - usually on a subsequent page load, and so might not help you if the large script you're loading is part of the page user visits first on your website.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I was thinking about these solutions, however, I'm not sure they really address the problem I have described. Please correct me if I'm wrong though! The script is not dynamic, I can generate its hash. However, even if I set CSP policy to accept scripts with a given hash, I would be allowed to load them with a script-tag but it still would not be possible to track download progress, right? The idea with service workers is interesting, but as it requires the user to install it (right?), it is too complex for my case here.

Comment: @WojciechDanilo Sorry, I should have elaborated on the Option 1 - added more explanation to the answer with sub-options with different examples and pros/cons. Hope it helps.

Comment: @WojciechDanilo As for the Service Worker option, user doesn't have to install them manually - it's something you do from JavaScript (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerContainer/register) but, as mentioned, it has a downside of not working on the first load.

Comment: Another thing that's worth mentioning: while Option 1 is way simpler and works on any load, it has a downside of losing streaming compilation, which might affect load times significantly on low-powered devices, especially for a bundle that large.

Comment: @WojciechDanilo Did this help at all?